# Python webbrowser module keep browser open

Tags: python, browser, module

I am trying to open a website with Python's webbrowser module, however, I want the browser to continue to stay open after the script is finished and not close out.

```
import webbrowser

# Logic/code that programmatically gets a URL

print(webbrowser.open(url))

# while True:
#    continue

print("script done")
```

If I run the code above I get:

```
>True
>script done
```

But no web page opens, no new tabs, etc.
If I uncomment the infinite While loop, then the browser/tab appears, and when I manually keyboard interrupt the process they disappear.

So, it appears the browser only lives while the script is running.

I want to open the browser to that page, and then leave it open.
Is there any way to do this with Python's webbrowser module or any built-in python modules?

Comment: Not reproducible. Your code works as expected for me. How do you run the code?

Comment: I have noted that if I already have a browser active it will open a new tab and that will persist. But if I do not have a window open then it will not open a new window unless the whole loop is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who might encounter this problem:

When running the script normally via command-line it works (python ./script.py).
But when running through Visual Studio Code's "Run without debugging", it does not work without the loop.

Comment: In my case it works both from shell/cmd and from built in terminal in vscode (run file in terminal)